# Animation with jquery doesn't work.

Tags: jquery

what is wrong with my code?
the animation is about to change width of a cell between two values.
the animation doesn't work. Could you fix the script section?
I'm in hurry.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .tbl{display: table;}
    .cell{display: table-cell;}
    .container{background: url("bgs/12.png")no-repeat;width: 179px;height: 119px;}
    #leftP{background: url("bgs/16.png")no-repeat right;width: 86px;height: 119px}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        function Animation(){
            $('leftP').animate({width:'48px'},"slow");
            $('leftP').animate({width:'86px'},"slow","",Animation());

        }
    });
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container tbl">
    <div id="leftP" class="cell width"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when should this be called?

Answer (score 3):

you are not calling `Animation()` anywhere... it won't do anything unless you call this function, `Animation()`, somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

You need to call function for the first time.

```
function Animation()
{
    $('#leftP').animate({width:'48px'},"slow");
    $('#leftP').animate({width:'86px'},"slow","",Animation());
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    Animation();
});
```

Also You forget to define `ID` in `jQuery` selector.

```
$('#leftP')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you defined `leftP` for animation but id must be `#leftP`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Animation(){
        $('#leftP').animate({width:'48px'},"slow");
        $('#leftP').animate({width:'86px'},"slow","",Animation());

    }

    Animation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code, I'll try to address them all:

1. Your selectors are wrong, you need to use the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) `#leftP`
2. You need to do the animations in sequence, so execute the second animation in the callback of the first animation.
3. You need to call the Animation-function the first time for everything to start. In my example I'm using an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Here is what I believe you are looking for.

```
$(function () {
    (function Animation(){
        $('#leftP').animate({width:'48px'},"slow", function () {
           $('#leftP').animate({width:'86px'},"slow","",Animation());
        });    
    })();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QUTym/)